# Is there any available Django already built package for login

Tags: django, authentication, authorization, admin

Django has its well designed admin site which is normally located at your-site/admin.

The interface is very powerful. However, you have to set permissions if you have multiple users with different rights and you have to modify a lot if the user asks you for very customised features.

So now my questions are:

1. should I build my own login site to provide website-specific features?
2. is there any already built package which I can re-use and add my own features into it?

Comment: Yes there is. It's the Django-Admin. Better to modify and customize than to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to use (and probably customize) a login application I always use [**django-registration**](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/).

It is a very complete app, I has email activation key and some other interesting features. And if you want to add/modify some new functionality you just have to create a new backend (you can inherit the common behaviour from the default backend.

- https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration
- https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration

Hope it helps

Comment: Although the question says "login" multiple times, it's not actually about logging in. The asker wants a better replacement for the admin app.

Comment: Hi julio.alegria, thanks for your reply! Actually, I really wanted to ask like what Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has said. BTW, with the django-registration, will the users have their personal page after being logged in? If yes, I think I can start add my own features there.

Comment: @TrongBang I misunderstood the question. **django-registration** redirects to /accounts/personal after logging, but I think you are the one that has to implement its behaviour (no personal page by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can create User Groups in django-admin to simplify assigning permissions instead of setting permissions to individual users.

Django-admin has a number of limitations, but there is a lot of extensions to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

The app django-userna will take your pain away.

http://django-userena.org/

But personnaly i use Pinax. When i start a project all account (login/password reset/email management etc ...) is built in and i can focus on what makes my project *different* instead of reinventing all the user management stuff.

Comment: Hi jpic, if I already used Django and built my website, can I use Pinax without rebuilding everything?